# How to perform an excel calculation on a vector that is stored in a single cell?

Tags: excel, vector, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with a vector of numbers (e.g. {1;2;3;4}) in each cell and I would like to perform simple calculations (eg =median(), =max(), (no VBA involved)) on each of those vectors. Somehow, Excel displays and performs calculations just the first value of each vector.

How can I get excel to use the full vector in calculations (and possibly for diagrams as well)?

What I have got:

```
Actual values in the cells           results in 
 +-A----------+-B----------+         +-A----------+-B----------+
1| ={1;2;3;4} | ={4;3;2;1} |        1|         1  |         4  |
 +------------+------------+         +------------+------------+
2| =median(a1)| =min(B1)   |        2|         1  |         4  |
 +------------+------------+         +------------+------------+
```

What I would like to have:

```
 +-A----------+-B----------+  
2|        2,5 |         1  |  
 +------------+------------+
```

What I have tried without avail is entering the values in the forms of

```
1;2;3;4 // {1;2;3;4} each will not be excepted as numbers in the calculations

{={1;2;3;4}]} with String+Shift+Enter will be handled like a single number as well.

(1;2;3;4) // =1; 2; 3; 4 // =(1;2;3;4) each result in an error on input ("not a formula")
```

Comment: You may need a small VBA "helper" function for this: see e.g.g https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/813953-store-retrieve-multiple-values-one-cell.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In A1:

```
={1,2,33,4,5}
```

(do not use Ctrl+Shift+Enter)

In B1:

```
=MAX(eval(A1))   '>>> 33
```

UDF "helper" function:

```
Function eval(ByVal rng As Range)
    eval = Application.Evaluate(rng.Formula)
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Without VBA:

```
A1:  1;2;3;4
```

Create a named formula:

```
seq_99   Refers to:  =IF(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))-1)*99)
```

Then:

```
=MEDIAN(IFERROR(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,";",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),""))
```

entered by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>

[image]